# Query results to variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 5 tables. I need to select the 4 most recent posts from one table and get the ID for those posts in four separate variables to use for queries from the other tables:

```
SELECT user FROM table1 WHERE subcategory = "$input" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4;
```

So there I have what I need. Now how can I assign those four userid results to new variables to be used in future queries on that same page.

I need to store it like this:

```
$user1 = "Sue";
$user2 = "Dave";
$user3 = "Alicia";
$user4 = "Tim";
```

So I can use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE user = $user1;
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE user = $user2;
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE user = $user3;
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE user = $user4;
```

Not to confuse the issue but: The ultimate goal is to have multiple rows but only four columns where all the data in the rows is ordered by the USER in the top row. It's important to note because each set of rows is separated by a description of what is contained in the data below it. These are just straight columns which would be easy. Something like this:

```
Sue            Dave             Alicia             Tim
Sue Profile    Dave Profile     Alicia Profile     Tim Profile
>>Answers to questions about work:
Sue Income     Dave Income      Alicia Income      Tim Income
Sue Years      Dave Years       Alicia Years       Tim Years
>>Answers to questions about school:
Sue Degree     Dave Degree      Alicia Degree      Tim Degree
Sue Schools    Dave Schools     Alicia Schools     Tim Schools
>>Answers to questions about life:
Sue Born       Dave Born        Alicia Born        Tim Born
Sue Parents    Dave Parents     Alicia Parents     Tim Parents
```

If I can read the id results into separate variables then for each section (question) I can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM income WHERE user = "Sue";
SELECT * FROM income WHERE user = "Dave";
SELECT * FROM income WHERE user = "Alicia";
SELECT * FROM income WHERE user = "Tim";

SELECT * FROM degree WHERE user = "Sue";
SELECT * FROM degree WHERE user = "Dave";
SELECT * FROM degree WHERE user = "Alicia";
SELECT * FROM degree WHERE user = "Tim";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better use JOINS then running multiple queries. Below is the code...

```
SELECT t1.user, t2.* FROM table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.user_id WHERE t1.subcategory = "$input" ORDER BY t1.id DESC LIMIT 4
```

I wish you can change the same key in both table in pace of **t1.id = t2.user_id**

Comment: I don't see how this gets me around the DIVIDERS (lines above that start with >>Answers) I have a join already and I can print my output in columns but not with the breaks. That's why I believe I need the first query to give me the users as four distinct variables.

Answer (score 0):

While what you are asking for can be achieved like this:

```
$id=1;
${"user".$id}="Sue";
```

so that $user1 will have "Sue", it would be so easy to use arrays for this purpose like this:

```
$id=1;
$user[$id]="Sue";
```

Or better, try to use Join in your query to fetch all data at once and then reformat it according to your needs.

Comment: I don't know that it's Sue until I run the query on table1 LIMIT 4 and get the four most recently active users. How do I get those users from the database and create the user variable for those 4 users? I'm missing it somehow.

Comment: I have this join now:

`SELECT videos.proid, videos.code, videos.views, pros.id, videos.qid, questions.question, pros.fname, pros.lname FROM videos INNER JOIN pros ON pros.id = videos.proid INNER JOIN questions ON videos.qid = questions.id WHERE subcatid = '$subcatid'  LIMIT 4`


That gets me the users names, their profile, and the answer to the first question. I am stuck getting the remaining questions AND breaking it up like the example in my original post/question. That's why I'm thinking I need multiple queries? Will to hire it done at this point ...

Comment: If you are not familiar with queries and want to keep things simple, you can loop to do it like anuj arora's answer or you will have to use a loop like `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))` to loop through each result and in the loop you will execute `select * from ... user="$user1"`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JOINS, then after executing the first query, you should use the foreach loop...

```
$user=array(); // i would suggest you for making an array
foreach($result_array as $key->$value)
{
    //here you will get the ids in $value['user']
    // and then you can use them in your queries
    // so no need to store them in different variables and remembering them.
    Edited:
    $user[$key] = $value['user'];
}
```

Comment: I get that but how do I assign "Sue" to $user1, "Dave" to $user2, "Alicia" to $user3, and "Tim" to $user4 so I can call $user1 - $user4 whenever I need it later in the script?

Comment: So I have this:  

`<?php $query = "SELECT proid FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";   
$result=mysql_query($query);  
$arr = array();  
while ($arr[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
echo "$arr[0]<br />"; }  
var_dump($arr); ?>`  

And it outputs this:  

`Array  
Array  
Array  
Array  
array(5) { [0]=> array(1) { ["proid"]=> string(2) "11" } [1]=> array(1) { ["proid"]=> string(2) "15" } [2]=> array(1) { ["proid"]=> string(2) "11" } [3]=> array(1) { ["proid"]=> string(2) "15" } [4]=> bool(false) }`  

 I'm not seeing how I can grab the proid from that array to use in my next query.

Comment: why are you assigning the whole array from mysql_fetch_assoc($result) to $arr[]. You have to get only the "proid". So, i will again suggest you to use the foreach loop, it will fulfill your requirement. Believe me and try for once.